# Count zeroes with Recursion keep crashing

Tags: c, recursion

My code is supposed to count the number of zeroes using recursion.

However my program keeps crashing.

Expected output:

```
Input: 10500
Result: 3
```

Code:

```
void rCountZeros2(int num, int *result) {
    if (num > 0) {
        if ((num % 10) == 0) {
            rCountZeros2((num / 10) + 1, *result);
        }
        rCountZeros2(num / 10, *result);
    } else if (num == 0) {
        *result = 1;
    }
    *result = num;
}
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: `rCountZeros2((num/10) + 1, *result);` - remove the `*`. And the other call as well. The compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: You've got a good start with giving us the input and expected output, now throw in the actual output you are getting.

Comment: Why the line `*result = num` ? I think, your algorithm to count zeros has to be reconsidered.

Comment: firstly, dont ignore compiler warnings (that you are surely getting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution with and without using pointers
Hope this helps

```
#include <stdio.h> // For C++ #include<iostream>
// Without using pointer
int count_zeros_recursive2(int num) {
  if (num % 10 == 0) {
    if (num > 19 || num < -19) {
      return 1 + count_zeros_recursive2(num / 10);
    }
    return 1;
  }
  if (num > 19 || num < -19) {
    return count_zeros_recursive2(num / 10);
  }
  return 0;
}
// Using pointer
void count_zeros_recursive(int num, int *result) {
  if (num % 10 == 0)
    *result = *result + 1;
  if (num > 19 || num < -19)
    count_zeros_recursive(num / 10, result);
}
int count_zeros(int num) {
  int result = 0;
  count_zeros_recursive(num, &result);
  //result = count_zeros_recursive2(num);
  return result;
}
int main() {
  int n;
  while (1) {
    scanf("%d", &n); // For C++ std::cin >> n;
    printf("%d\n", count_zeros(n));// For C++ std::cout << n << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

eg
 Input: 1010 
   Output: 2 
   Input: 0
   Output: 1
   Input: 10204012410
   Output: 4
   Input: -101
   Output: 1

Answer (score 1):

I prefer returning the result instead of passing the pointer to the result.
Stop condition is when the number is a single digit, then if 0 you have 1 zero, otherwise none.
If the number is not a single digit, calculate the number of zeros in the number without the lowest digit `(num/10)` and add 1 to the returned value if the lowest digit was 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_zeros_recursive(int num) 
{
    int res = 0;
    int num_without_lowest_digit = num/10;

    if(num_without_lowest_digit == 0)
    {
        res = (num == 0);
    }
    else
    {
        res = count_zeros_recursive(num_without_lowest_digit);
        if (num % 10 == 0)
        {
           res++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}


int main(void) {
    int nums[] = { 202, 7, 100, 10500, 10234, 10000};
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]); ++i)
    {
        printf("Number %d has %d zeros\n", nums[i], count_zeros_recursive(nums[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Tested here](https://ideone.com/jYLNW4)

```
Number 202 has 1 zeros
Number 7 has 0 zeros
Number 100 has 2 zeros
Number 10500 has 3 zeros
Number 10234 has 1 zeros
Number 10000 has 4 zeros
```

Comment: The questioner possibly wanted to pass a pointer as a parameter, since he also chose the tag "pointer". With a pointer, you could simply sum all zeros of your array of numbers.

Comment: @TomKuschel, Same this can be achieved without passing the result as a pointer. Just instead passing the `result` by pointer, it can add the returned value: `result += count_zeros_recursive(nums[i]);`. As I mentioned in the answer, I prefer this because then the function is self contained and there is no doubts if it has to check for a `NULL` value or should it or should not initialize the `*result` to 0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you really want to use a pointer for some reason. Here's a full solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rCountZeros2(int num, int *result)
{
  if(num>0)
  {
    if( (num % 10) == 0)
    {
      *result = *result + 1;
    }
    rCountZeros2(num/10, result);
  }
}

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  int n;
  n = scanf("%d", &n);
  int *result = &i;
  rCountZeros2(n, result);
  printf("%d\n", *result);
}
```

So what will happen is that you're effectively just updating the value at the location which `result` is pointing to, which means that you're really just storing the count in the variable `i`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass a pointer if you can use a functional approach. Just return the value.

```
long recursiveZeroesCount(long num) {
        if(num == 0) return 1;
        if(num < 10) return 0;
        if(num % 10 == 0) return 1 + recursiveZeroesCount(num / 10);
        else return recursiveZeroesCount(num / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program has undefined behavior because you pass the value of the `*result` instead of the pointer to the result variable to recursive calls.  Furthermore, your algorithm is flawed as you cannot use this API recursively because the recursive calls update the result as well as the current call, a very impractical situation.

Here is a corrected version without recursion:

```
void rCountZeros2(int num, int *result) {
    int count = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if (num % 10 == 0)
            count++;
        num /= 10;
        if (num == 0)
            break;
    }
    *result = count;
}
```

And here is a recursive implementation with a simpler API:

```
int rCountZeros2(int num) {
    if (num % 10 == 0) {
        if (num == 0)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 1 + rCountZeros2(num / 10);
    } else {
        if (num < 10)
            return 0;
        else
            return rCountZeros2(num / 10);
    }
}
```

The above function can be simplified as a single statement:

```
int rCountZeros2(int num) {
    return !(num % 10) + ((num < 10) ? 0 : rCountZeros2(num / 10));
}
```